# Overloading operator '=' and [] for writing to position in the file

Tags: c++, file-io, operator-overloading

I need to overload operators [] and '=' for a class that contains file for writing to position in the file.
For example this code should work:

```
    UserFileClass File;
    printf("%c",File[53]);  //printing character from the 53 position in the file
    File[34]='d';   //34th character in the file will be rewriten with d
```

But how to do that, if after overloading [] for returning char, we cannot overwrite anything in the object with '=' operator. I tried to do that in other way but it doesn't work too:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>

    using namespace std;

    class File
    {


fstream file;
    char buffer;
    int charPos;
public:

    File(string fileName);
    ~File(){file.close();};

    File & operator[](int position);
    File & operator=(const char &);
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream,File);
};

File::File(string fileName)
{
    file.open(fileName);
    if(!file)
    {
        cerr<<"File reading error";
        exit(1);
    }
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream outStream, File obj)
{
    outStream<<obj.buffer;
    return outStream;
}

File & File::operator[](int position)
{
    file.seekg(position);
    if(file.eof())
    {
        buffer='\0';
    }
    else
    {
        file.read(&buffer,1);
        charPos=position;
    }
    return *this;
}

File & File::operator=(const char & charValue)
{
    file.seekg(charPos);
    file.write(&charValue,1);
    return *this;
}

void main()
{
    File userFile("file.txt");
    cout<<userFile[2];
    userFile[4]='a';
}
```

Compilation Error:Error     2   error C2248: std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios:cannot access private member ...

Comment: `std::ostream` isn't copyable.

Comment: `printf` is C, not C++.

Comment: outStream<<obj.buffer; here you are accessing private member "buffer"...write a getter for buffer

Comment: @ZacHowland Formally, it's both.  But of course there's no reason to use it in C++, given it's notable problems.

Comment: @JamesKanze Only through the inheritance mechanism that C++ has with C.  When asking a question tagged as "C++" (and not tagged as "C"), `printf` (and any of its sister functions) does not belong.

Comment: @ZacHowland I totally agree that no competent programmer would use `printf` if `std::ostream` is around, and he knows it.  The `printf` family is particularly poorly designed (but it's hard to do better, given the constraints of a purely library solution and the language C).  Still, you can't really say "it's not C".  (And much of the C library legacy is essential C++; e.g. `<math.h>`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual solution would be for the `operator[]` to return
a proxy, along the lines of:

```
class UserFile
{
    //...
    char get( int index ) const { ... }
    void set( int index, char newValue ) { ... }
    class Proxy
    {
        UserFile* myOwner;
        int myIndex;
    public:
        Proxy( UserFile* owner, int index )
            : myOwner( owner )
            , myIndex( index )
        {
        }
        Proxy const& operator=( char ch ) const
        {
            myOwner->set( myIndex, ch ):
            return *this;
        }
        operator char() const
        {
            return myOwner->get( myIndex );
        }
    };
    Proxy operator[]( int index )
    {
        return Proxy( this, index );
    }
};
```

Of course, this won't work when matching `...` in a function
call, so you can't use it directly with `printf`.  (But then,
there's really no excuse for using `printf` in C++.  Or any
other function which has varargs.)  You'd have to explicitly
cast it the `char`:

```
printf( "%c", static_cast<char>( file[42] ) );
```

Comment: You could do it without the proxy by using `seekg` and `read`, though.  And it would not require a cast.

Comment: @ZacHowland The goal, IIUC, is to support the `[]` syntax.  How else would you do it without the proxy.  (And since this is C++, the fact that it doesn't work seamlessly with `printf` isn't an issue; it _does_ work with `std::ostream`.)

Comment: If that is his goal, then this may be an XY problem.  The behavior of `operator[]` would have to be drastically different depending on the direction (e.g. `file[3] = 'd'` would have to write to the file, `cout << file[3]` would have to read from it).  Loading the entire file into a `string` and manipulating it would be a better solution (at the very least, it would decrease all the disk reads and writes).

Comment: @ZacHowland I think that is his goal; it is, at any rate, a frequent goal, and a proxy is the usual solution.  As to reading the file into memory and working on it there: that doesn't really change the issue, because you still have to catch the writes, and mark the buffer as dirty, so you know to write it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream outStream, File obj)
```

That declaration is wrong.  It should be:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& outStream, File obj)
                    ^^^^^^^^ .................... Note the &
```

Additionally, I don't see a need for this class at all.  It seems to be a wrapper around `fstream`, but is doing nothing that `fstream` does not already do, and has to use it to boot.

Side note:  Assuming this class is defined in a header file, you do **not** want to place a `using namespace std;` in the header file!